# How can I pass a url to the build library(lib) using angular

Tags: angular

I tried to use a separate angular project which is created using angular libraries. Now I need to pass a url to that created lib. Can I pass parameters to that library ?
I am using that created library as bellow in my working project.

. 
I need to pass different urls for dev and production environment to that library and use it in my working project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, have a tour on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I got it. First create a angular project to take some data from back-end and display. Then create a library using that project and publish it somewhere. Then use that library in another project. I need to  use that library in different environment as  'dev' and 'production'. So  I need to pass a url to that library project. can you suggest a someway to do that ?